# Property or method not defined on the instance but referenced during render I Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm getting the following error.

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "updateData" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

As far I can tell by the code, the method is there, so I'm stuck on something that I miss due to my ignorance of Vuex. I've googled the matter and got quite a few answers but none of them made me any wiser what to do. It seems to be something with scope, I'm sensing.

I also get the error below but I suspect that it's the same root cause for both so solving the one will resolve the other.

> [Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined 
>   (found in component  at ...)

The markup is as follow. I've checked that the path goes to the right location. At the moment I'm not sure at all how to even start to troubleshoot it. Any hints would be appreciated.

```
<template>
  <div id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li @click="updateData">Update</li>
      <li @click="resetData">Reset</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { updateData, resetData } from "../vuex_app/actions";

  export default {
    vuex: {
      getters: { activeDataRow: state => state.activeDataRow },
      actions: { updateData, resetData }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Edit**

After input I improved the export to include *methods* property like so. (Still the same error remaining, though.)

```
export default {
  vuex: {
    getters: { activeDataRow: state => state.activeDataRow }, 
    actions: { updateData, resetData }, 
    methods:{ 
      updateData: () => this.$store.dispatch("updateData"), 
      resetData: () => this.$store.dispatch("resetData")
    }
  }
}
```

Do I have to do something extra in the store? It looks like this.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
Vue.use(Vuex);

const state = { dataRows: [], activeDataRow: {} };
const mutations = {
    UPDATE_DATA(state, data) { state.dataRows = data; state.activeDataRow = {}; },
    RESET_DATA(state) { state.dataRows = []; state.activeDataRow = {}; }
};

export default new Vuex.Store({ state, mutations });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add the imported functions in the methods of Vue component, like following. You can take help of `mapActions` as explained in the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html). This is needed to map `this.updateDate` to `this.$store.dispatch('updateDate')`.

```
<script>
  import { updateData, resetData } from "../vuex_app/actions";
  import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

   export default {
    vuex: {
      getters: { activeDataRow: state => state.activeDataRow },
      actions: { updateData, resetData }
    },
    methods: {
       ...mapActions(['updateData', 'resetData'])
    }
  }
</script>
```

### Edited

In case you dont want to use `mapActions`, you can use `this.$store.dispatch` as you are using in your example, however you need to have methods at vue compoenent level ([documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers)) and not insise vuex, as following:

```
export default {
  vuex: {
    getters: { activeDataRow: state => state.activeDataRow }, 
    actions: { updateData, resetData }
  }, 
  methods:{ 
    updateData: () => this.$store.dispatch("updateData"), 
    resetData: () => this.$store.dispatch("resetData")
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's the part with *$store* coming from? Is it an internal utility field of Vue? I don't recognize the name from other contexts and it looks to me like a jQuery style variable (almost)...

Comment: @KonradViltersten `this.$store` is your vuex store for this vue component, using this you can access vuex store or trigger mutations or dispatch actions. You can see its example uses [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=this.%24store).

Comment: I've found it, thanks. The problem is that the three dots ("...") doesn't work. I've read up on it but at the moment, it's a bit too many loose parts for me to feel convenient. How could I rewrite methods: ... part with old style of JS? I'll try to figure out how to configure webpack to work the spread operator later, I hope.

Comment: I solved the spread-opeartor issue but the original problem is still there. Please feel free to take a look at the edit.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: In your version, you've nested `methods` inside your `vuex` object - it needs to be one level higher, as it is in saurabh's example.