# What is the significance of @ in click when using WebPack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

In [one of the guides for Vue framework](https://coligo.io/learn-vuex-by-building-notes-app/) I've seen the following passage.

```
<template>
  <div id="blopp">
    <ul>
      <li @click="doStuff">Stuff</li>
      <li @click="doThings">Things</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

I'd like to know what that means and how it affects the build. Googling gave nothing because google disregards special characters and common words when searching so all I got was a bunch of references to jQuery's API and some hits on W3Schools.

I have a hunch that it's got to do with WebPack transformations but it could be specific to Vue too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nothing to do with Webpack - it's part of Vue's binding syntax. `@` is used as a shortcut syntax for [`v-on:`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on), which is used for binding functions/statements to events.

So in your example, the `click` event on the first `li` is bound to the `doStuff` function, and the `click` event on the second `li` is bound to the `doThings` function.

Comment: So, *<li @click="updateData">Update</li>* is *<li v-on:click="updateData">Update</li>*?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: Exactly :)

Comment: Well, as long as we're on the subject of syntax in Vue - I can't figure out how to deploy the "..." operator for *mapActions* and my clickaroos aren't working proeprly. Should I ask a new question or is it something super simple too? ([Here's the suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40878876/1525840) that I try to implement.)

Comment: @KonradViltersten: Are you using Babel? The [object spread](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) syntax is currently only a proposal rather than a confirmed part of the JavaScript spec, so you need an extra Babel plugin to use it. That plugin can be found here, with installation instructions: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/

Comment: @KonradViltersten: Or alternatively, you can just go without using `mapActions` like so: `methods: { updateData: () => this.$store.dispatch("updateData"), resetData: () => this.$store.dispatch("resetData") }`. The resulting object is the same, `mapActions` just makes it looks a little prettier.

Comment: Awesome, this (uglier, old style) version you suggested worked out. Still not sure why it didn't like the spread-operator (that's what the dot-dot-dot is called, right?) but at least it's not complaining about that. Would you have time to [take a look there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40877970/1525840) if I entered it correctly? Since the original error is still there, I'm afraid that I've done something else in a wrong way.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: Commented on the answer to that question :)