# object spread operator detected as an error on webpack for node 8.6

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to upgrade my application's node version from node6 to node8.6 which supports spread operator natively, all works fine until I try to compile my node script using webpack.

I've created a test script (testing native support for async/await too, for the occasion):

```
const fs = require('fs')
const {promisify} = require('util')

const app = async () => {
  try {
    const todosString = await promisify(fs.readFile)('todos.txt', {
      encoding: 'utf8',
    })
    return todosString
      .split('\n')
      .filter(Boolean)
      .reduce((acc, val) => ({...acc, [val]: true}), {})
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('wooot', e)
  }
}

app().then(console.log)
```

Here is the webpack configuration:

```
const path = require('path')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {filename: '[name].js'},
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  node: {
    __dirname: true,
    __filename: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
            [
              'env',
              {
                targets: {
                  node: 'current',
                  modules: false,
                },
              },
            ],
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

And here is my webpack build output:
[image]

The object spread gives an error and async/await is transpiled by default, even `target: 'node'` is set on the webpack config...

UPDATE this is the package.json: [image]

Comment: Nit: It's not an operator, it's just syntax. Operators have a single value result. Spread doesn't, and can't.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: If anyone else is wondering: Yes, Node v8.6 really does support object spread, not just array spread. I double-checked.

Comment: Remember MDN is community-edited and while normally good-to-excellent it *is* sometimes wrong. That's the case with the Spanish article you linked above. The English version was also wrong for along time before being corrected (and still has "operator" in the URL, sadly). (A couple of the polyfills the site had for a long time were quite off, as well.) If you want the straight dope, go to [the specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/).

Comment: I think at the moment object spread is not available to babel. You might try using Stage 2 presets. There's a SO Q/A here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897154/spread-operator-not-recognized-by-webpack-under-vue

Comment: Oh dang! (Its Italian BTW) :)

Comment: @Mark_M the goal is to not transpile the object spread operator, as its native to node 8.6 now!

Comment: @cl0udw4lk3r: OMG I can't believe I said Spanish. Parlo *meglio* italiano che parlo spanolo! Mi scusa, mi guardavo troppo in fretta!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I had to translate that just to see how badly you had to govel for getting the language wrong :D

Answer (score 0):

`npm install babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread --save`

and include the below query in first object if the rules array in webpack.config file

```
query: {
      plugins:[ 'transform-object-rest-spread' ]
    }
```

Comment: This will not solve my issue: node 8.6 supports object spread natively and I wont use babel to transpile it anymore!